# T-SQL How to run procedure recursively?

Tags: t-sql, recursion

in my procedure, I try to run itself recursively when some conditions appear

(I simplified the code just to find out how to do the recursion)

Firstly I created the procedure with commented the BEGIN..END body, and then:

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_new_customer_task]
     @TaskTypeID decimal,
     @TaskName nvarchar(1000),
     @IDCsrUser decimal,
     @TaskStatusID decimal,
     @ActualDateParam datetime,
     @isNextDate bit
AS
BEGIN   
      [dbo].[insert_new_customer_task](@TaskTypeID,@TaskName,@IDCsrUser,@TaskStatusID,@ActualDateParam,1)
END
GO
```

but I see an error inside BEGIN..END **Incorrect syntax near 'dbo'.** So how to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `EXEC` and no brackets on the parameters, i.e.

```
EXEC [dbo].[insert_new_customer_task] @TaskTypeID,@TaskName,
     @IDCsrUser,@TaskStatusID,@ActualDateParam,1
```

Answer (score 3):

Add EXEC command and remove the parentheses around parameters:

```
EXEC [dbo].[insert_new_customer_task]
     @TaskTypeID, @TaskName,@IDCsrUser,@TaskStatusID,@ActualDateParam,1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_new_customer_task](
     @TaskTypeID decimal,
     @TaskName nvarchar(1000),
     @IDCsrUser decimal,
     @TaskStatusID decimal,
     @ActualDateParam datetime,
     @isNextDate bit)
AS
BEGIN   
      EXEC [dbo].[insert_new_customer_task] @TaskTypeID,@TaskName,@IDCsrUser,@TaskStatusID,@ActualDateParam,1
END
GO
```

you need parenthesis around procedure definition, not in body where you call it.